# Tridion CM 2013 HR1 installer error: Reconfiguration success or error status: 1603

Tags: 2013-sp1, cme

Our client's server admin is attempting to upgrade one of their environments from 2013 SP1 to 2013 SP1 HR1.  Upon running the installer the following error occurs.

[image: failed to install product]

The logs show this message:

```
Windows Installer reconfigured the product. Product Name: SDL Tridion Content Manager. Product Version: 7.1.1312. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: SDL Tridion. Reconfiguration success or error status: 1603.

Or

Application: SDLTridion2013SP1HR1.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.

Exception Info: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
Exception thrown by custom action:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unable to load config file D:\Tridion\config\cm_cnfg_git : Unable to decrypt data
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDSXGit.ConfigurationLegacyClass.Upgrade()
   at CSharpCustomActions.GitConfigurationCustomActions.GitConfigurationExecute(Session session)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object parameters, Object arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.CustomActionProxy.InvokeCustomAction(Int32 sessionHandle, String entryPoint, IntPtr remotingDelegatePtr)
CustomAction GitConfigurationExecute returned actual error code 1603
```

I've looked at a some generic Windows help articles:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/834484

Also found this, Solution 2: http://www.helptouser.com/tridion/7487-unable-to-load-config-file-cm-cnfg-git-unable-to-decrypt-data.html, and this looks like the answer, but I'd like a bit more information on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Customer Support returned with the following answer:

This error is usually due to a problem with an OS system DLL not being properly registered. On your system, find the `capicom.dll` (usually under `/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/CAPICOM`). From the command line, re-register this DLL:

```
regsvr32 /u capicom.dll

regsvr32 capicom.dll
```

In addition, you may also need to re-register the following Tridion DLLs:

- `cm_bl.dll`
- `cm_tom.dll`
- `cm_dal.dll`
- `cm_dal_oracle8.dll`
- `cm_dal_sql2000.dll`

Restart the server after re-registering the DLL, and let us know if the error persists after manually re-applying the Windows update.

Comment: And did this solve it?

Comment: Yes sir. It did indeed